# How to give specific id and using apollo client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

It is work for backend.

Backend

```
type Query {
    allUsers: [User!]!
    allPosts: [Post!]!
    singleDetail(id:Int): Post!
}
```

resolver

```
singleDetail: async(_parent:any, args: { id: number }) => {
    return await prisma.post.findUnique({
        where:{
          id: args.id
        }
    })
}
```

But Frontend is not work.This is Posts List.
I want when clicking the detail button, it's displayed single detail post.

```
const detailPostButton = (id:number) => SinglePostShow({id})

    return (
      <Col span={6} key={id}>
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'beige' }}>
          <p>title:{title}</p>
          <p>content:{content}</p>
          <div className="buttonPlace">
            <Button onClick={() => deletePostButton(id)}>削除</Button>
            <div>
              <NavLink to={`/AllPostsShow/${id}`}>
                <Button onClick={() => detailPostButton(id)}>
                  詳細
                </Button>
              </NavLink>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Col>
    )
```

this is a single post file.

```
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client'

const SINGLE_POST_DETAIL = gql`
  query singleDetail($id: Int) {
      singleDetail(id: $id) {
          id
          title
          content
      }
  }
`

export const SinglePostShow = ({id}:{id:number}) => {
  console.log(id,'id')

  const {
    data,
    loading,
    error
  } = useQuery(SINGLE_POST_DETAIL,{
    variables:{
      id
    },
  })

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>
  if (error) return <p>Error...</p>

  const {id:singleId,title,content} = data
  

  return (
    <div key={singleId}>
      detailForm
      <input>{title}</input>
      <input>{content}</input>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SinglePostShow
```

I can get id from const detailPostButton = (id:number) => SinglePostShow({id}).
But how to handle apollo....

and when clicking detail button, it's error like the following a pic.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48rNB.png)

Comment: Good details on the post! Just remember to format your posts to be easily-readable by others (such as good indentation, which I fixed for ya)